# Create multiple output files based on the contents of JSON

Tags: bash, command-line-interface, jq

I have a json array of objects.I filter it with jq to get data I want:

```
cat [{'name': 'a', 'content': {'nested': 'important content'}}, ...] >> jq ".[]|select(MY_FILTER)|.name,.content.nested"
```

How can I write the output to multiple files, each named `{.name}.sql` and containing `{.content.nested}`

I've tried experimenting with echo, tee, --unbuffered and --raw, but with no success

Comment: that is not valid JSON, do you mean double quotes in your input

Comment: Also could you post an input with more than just one record?

Comment: more records with similar structure

Comment: exact structure of the records is not relevant, it's simply to show jq selecting two pieces of information from each

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an array of JSON objects coming-in, you can pipe that to `jq` and form the resulting file with a tool like `awk` (note that a simple bash loop could also be used)

Pipe the command or the JSON array of objects to the following pipeline

```
jq  -cr '.[] | [.name, .content.nested] | join("\t")' | 
  awk -F'\t' '{fname = $1".sql"; print $2 > fname; close(fname)}'
```

If you suspect `\t` to be present in your data and want to delimit with a non-occuring character, use the NULL delimit as

```
jq -cjr '.[] | (.name, "\u0000", .content.nested)' | 
  awk -F'\0' '{fname = $1".sql"; print $2 > fname; close(fname)}'
```

Comment: that worked, thanks. awk is not my usual go to tool

Comment: a follow-up question - any advice what could I use instead of tabs in case the input contained some?

Comment: @sumek Any delimiter of your choice , ; : which is not present in your input. Change it on both jq’s join and in Awk

Comment: @sumek: See edit with NULL delimit